# Seperating the O.D.E $\frac{dv}{dt} = mg - \kappa v$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I am having some trouble seperating the following (autonomous) O.D.E.

$$\frac{dv}{dt} = mg - \kappa v$$

From what I understand, I have to get the $v$ to the left side while having the $\kappa$ on right side with $dt$. The solution is given by:

$$\begin{align}
\frac{dv}{dt} &= mg - \kappa v \\
\frac{dv}{\left(v-\frac{mg}{k}\right)} &= -\kappa dt
\end{align}$$

What I am having trouble understanding is how he (the prof.) managed to seperate the O.D.E like that. Can someone please show the steps?

Thanks!

Comment: I realize you have all the information you require @gekkostate but I wonder (following on from your earlier "how did I miss that" statement) that you may have mixed up the symbol $\kappa$ with an arbitrary $k$. As per the $\frac{mg}{k}$ term in the third symbolic line down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
mg - \kappa v = -\kappa \left ( v - \frac {mg}\kappa\right )
$$

Comment: How did I miss that?! `:)` Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, one may put the equation in a more convenient form for direct integration.  For example, write the equation as

$$\frac{d v}{d t} + \kappa v = m g$$

Multiply through by $e^{\kappa t}$ on both sides.  In this case, the LHS looks like a derivative of a product:

$$e^{\kappa t} \frac{d v}{dt} + e^{\kappa t} \kappa v = \frac{d}{dt} \left (e^{\kappa t} v \right ) = e^{\kappa t} m g$$

Integrating both sides:

$$e^{\kappa t} v(t) = \frac{m g}{\kappa} e^{\kappa t} + C$$

where $C$ is a constant of integration.  You may then solve for $v(t)$ easily from here.

Comment: Thanks for the alternative way, it always helps!