# Solving a first O.D.E

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm solving a rocket problem with the following O.D.E:

$$\frac{dv}{dt}=-g-\frac{k}{m}\, v^2$$

with $g$ as gravitational constant, and $m$ (no changing mass) and $k$ are also constants. Given the initial condition $v(0)=V_0$ m/s, how to go about fnding its analytical solution?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What are your attempts solving this problem?

Comment: It's a separable equation

Comment: I was looking at this ODE to see if I can treat it as a separable equation: [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/451140/seperating-the-o-d-e-fracdvdt-mg-kappa-v)

Comment: The physics of this equation is only valid for $v>0$. In general it should be $\dot v=-g-\frac km v|v|$, as the air friction always acts to reduce the velocity, that is as a force in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the equation as $$\frac{dt}{dv}=-\frac 1{g+\frac{k}{m}\, v^2}$$

$$-t+C=\int \frac {dv}{g+\frac{k}{m}\, v^2}$$ Now, a suitable change of variable will make you facing a very well know integral.

Comment: @macy. What is the simplest integral (you know it) where the numerator is $\color{red}{1}$ and the denominator contains $\color{red}{(\text{something}+x^2)}$ ?

Comment: it would be $\arctan(x)$ is that something is unity.

Comment: @macy. Good bet !

Answer (score 1):

As a Riccati equation one approach is to set $v=\frac{m}{k}\frac{u'}{u}$ so that you get to
$$
\frac{m}{k}\frac{u''}{u}-\frac{m}{k}\frac{u'^2}{u^2}=-g-\frac{m}{k}\frac{u'^2}{u^2}
\implies
u''+\frac{kg}{m}u=0
$$
and this is now a harmonic oscillator equation with frequency $\omega=\sqrt{\frac{kg}{m}}$ and thus solutions $u=A\cosωt+B\sinωt$ from which you can reconstruct the function $v$.