# What is the final answer of $m\dot{v}=mg-kv^2$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics

I tried solving this equation using several different methods but I never got to an answer. I tried using partial integration and at last I got 
$m/\sqrt{mg}\ln mg-kv^2 = t+c$

I even tried using substitution but I could not get an answer. I would be really grateful if someone could help me completing my solution or even linking me to somewhere where there is a conclusive answer. 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Wolfram alpha says the solution is: $\frac{m}{k}\cdot ln(cosh(\frac{\sqrt{mg\cdot k}\cdot (m K_1 + t) }{m}))$

Comment: @Sandra Please use MathJax and edit the expressions. It will be more clear then.

Comment: I've done my best to convert what you wrote to MathJax. Please double-check my assumptions about what was intended.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3059298/115115 for the same problem (up to sign differences that may turn into sign errors.)

Answer (score 4):

Since $dt=\frac{m dv}{mg-kv^2}$, you can easily express $t-t_0$ (say) in terms of $v$ using the hyperbolic arctangent. You can then invert this to get $v$ in terms of $t-t_0$. I'll leave integration to $x=x_0+\int_0^t v(t^\prime) dt^\prime$ to you, using the fact that $\int\tanh u du=\ln\cosh u+C$.